# Unexpectedly logout from Xfce4 session because of nouveau driver bug

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nouveau, devuan

I have an experience noteing regular breaks of xfce4 sessions due to video driver bugs. This always happens when I visit websites overloaded with JavaScript like analytics or some exchanges with trade charts.

I use Firefox and Falcon now but that does not help me (Chromium is not the reason).

I removed all firmware-* packages but still use intel microcode, and use only opensource, I hope.

Now Nvidia GeForce GT 710 is used, but also I have on-kernel Intel Graphic card - CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630].

What should I do with my bugs?

```
# tail /var/log/messages  -n5
Jun  8 13:21:46 devuan kernel: [80026.336206] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Jun  8 14:54:28 devuan kernel: [85588.333195] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: channel 2: killed
Jun  8 14:54:28 devuan kernel: [85588.333196] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: runlist 0: scheduled for recovery
Jun  8 14:54:28 devuan kernel: [85588.333199] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: engine 0: scheduled for recovery
Jun  8 14:54:28 devuan kernel: [85588.333206] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[8149]: channel 2 killed!

# lspci -v
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129, IOMMU group 1
    Memory at db000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Memory at d8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_current_drm, nvidia_current

# lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:129 memory:db000000-dbffffff memory:d0000000-d7ffffff memory:d8000000-d9ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:130 memory:da000000-daffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)

# find /dev -group video
/dev/fb0
/dev/dri/card1
/dev/dri/renderD129
/dev/dri/card0
/dev/dri/renderD128

# uname -a
Linux devuan 5.10.0-14-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.113-1 (2022-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux

# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Devuan
Description:    Devuan GNU/Linux 4 (chimaera)
Release:    4
Codename:   chimaera

#apt list --installed | grep -i firm
#

# apt list --installed | grep -i intel
intel-media-va-driver/stable,now 21.1.1+dfsg1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
intel-microcode/now 3.20210608.2 amd64 [installed,local]
libdrm-intel1/stable,now 2.4.104-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libintellij-annotations-java/stable,now 20.1.0-1 all [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-video-intel/stable,now 2:2.99.917+git20200714-1+deb11u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed nvidia firmware and also I blacklisted nouveau and issue is gone.

```
apt list --installed | grep firmw
apt purge firmware-misc-nonfree firmware-linux-free
apt purge nvidia-driver
apt purge nvidia-persistenced
rm /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf
rm /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-blacklists-nouveau.conf
rm /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia*
update-grub2
sudo update-initramfs -u
reboot
```

not helped, because nouveau is loaded:

```
**Devuan bugs: unexpectedly logout from xfce4 session when use browser oveloaded with javascript like google analytics
Jun  8 14:54:28 devuan kernel: [85588.333195] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: channel 2: killed
Jun  8 14:54:28 devuan kernel: [85588.333196] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: runlist 0: scheduled for recovery
Jun  8 14:54:28 devuan kernel: [85588.333199] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: engine 0: scheduled for recovery
Jun  8 14:54:28 devuan kernel: [85588.333206] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[8149]: channel 2 killed!
Jun  8 15:54:36 devuan kernel: [89196.276446] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: channel 2: killed
Jun  8 15:54:36 devuan kernel: [89196.276448] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: runlist 0: scheduled for recovery
Jun  8 15:54:36 devuan kernel: [89196.276451] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: engine 0: scheduled for recovery
Jun  8 15:54:36 devuan kernel: [89196.276455] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: engine 6: scheduled for recovery
Jun  8 15:54:36 devuan kernel: [89196.276459] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[13885]: channel 2 killed!
lspci -v
  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau


cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
update-initramfs -u
reboot

lspci -v
  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

that helped, cause nvidia driver is used